# Installing and running .exe as Windows service using WiX

Tags: python, windows, wix

i have a following problem:
I had setup.py file - I used "python setup.py bdist_wininst" to changed it to .exe.  Installation of this isn't silent, when i'am launching .exe file the installator asks me to choose desirable python installation i want setup.exe to install into. 
Now I want to install this .exe file as Windows service, here is my Wix code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="TelnetInstaller" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="manufactur" UpgradeCode="24E13D15-CFF7-48EB-82EA-B1F9547F846C">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="$(var.ProjectDir)\License.rtf"/>
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLLOCATION"/>


    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate  EmbedCab="yes"/>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id='TempFolder'>
        <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="MyApp" >
          <Component Id='MyComponent'   Guid='722E35C2-58F1-417D-AB02-2968CAF7C6D2'>
            <File Id="mysetup_exe" Source="$(var.ProjectDir)\TelnetDS-0.9.win32.exe" />
           <ServiceInstall
              Id="ServiceInstaller"
              Type="ownProcess"
              Vital="yes"
              Name="Telnet"
              DisplayName="Telnet DS service"
              Description="DS for communicating with devices via Telnet protocol."
              Start="auto"              
              ErrorControl="normal"     
              Interactive="yes"
              >

            </ServiceInstall>
            <ServiceControl Id="StartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="Telnet" Wait="yes" />
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Feature Id="MainApplication" Title="Main Application" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="MyComponent" />
    </Feature>
    <!--<CustomAction Id="run_setup" FileKey="mysetup_exe"  ExeCommand="" 
                  Execute="deferred" Impersonate="yes"
                   Return="check" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="run_setup" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed </Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>-->
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Problem is, that during installation .msi file generated in Wix there is a problem: "Verify that you have sufficient privileges to install system service"
Now I don't know what is the cause of this - is it the case that I indeed don't have this privileges or I am trying to install .exe which needs some input data from me ( choosing python installation folder ) as service.
Do you know how to fix this? Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following,

Make sure all services windows are closed before starting install/uninstall or

Installing the .NET framework version 4.5

[Error 1920 service failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061057/error-1920-service-failed-to-)[start-verify-that-you-have-sufficient-privileges-t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061057/error-1920-service-failed-to-start-verify-that-you-have-sufficient-privileges-t)

Comment: Ok please check and confirm about NSSM.

Comment: It works, NSSM has a nice set of commands that you can run in cmd.exe.
I just added custom action that launches batch file, which uses NSSM comands to  install and run my service