# Service 'MongoDB Server' (MongoDB) failed to start

Tags: mongodb, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to install mongo DB on my local machine with the installer from the official website. But I'm continuously getting this message, can someone help?

[image]
I've tried the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061057/error-1920-service-failed-to-start-verify-that-you-have-sufficient-privileges-t) but didn't help.

Comment: Are you logged in as an administrator?

Comment: Yes, actually there's only one account on the computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest doing the following:

Hit **Win+R** to open up you **run.exe** then inside of it enter **services.msc** to open up `services`. Try locating the service under the name of ***`MongoDB Server`*** and set the `Startup Type` manually to **`Automatic`** - [In addition to that, you could set the `username` and `password` manually. If you get a message saying the user was granted login as a service right, try hitting retry on the `MSI` dialog and see if it starts].

**Important:**
Don't forget to save and close everything (`services.msc`) before continuing.

---

Also very **important**, you should (must) check your **`.NET framework`** version and update it to version **4.5** and above. You could download a software like eg *Driver Booster* to update all of your drivers and additional components that are outdated.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was due to the absence of .NET framework.

Comment: hi, the same error I am getting while installing mongodb in machine, how did you upgrade .net framework version

Comment: @KuldeepKoranga https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55170

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue. My problem was the installation location. I was trying to install under `C:\MongoDB`. I resolved it by installing in the default MongoDb location which is `C:\Program Files\MongoDB`.

Comment: I was scared that this could be the problem, I have a C:\Bin folder where I keep all binaries (Php, Java, MySQL, et cetera) and it's not the first time that I have problem with permissions with services in this path. Thanks for sharing your solution!

Answer (score 1):

For me this is usually an issue with the configuration file %ProgramFiles%\MongoDB\Server\x.x\bin\mongod.cfg

At some time there was an invalid option "snmp" enabled (only valid in enterprise version).

Nowadays, although the installer asks for directories for data and logs it doesn't ALWAYS seem to use these, but defaults to %MONGO_DATA_PATH% or %MONGO_LOG_PATH%, respectively. I don't know where these should be defined, but the server fails at accessing c:\data\db (which doesn't exist). So you have to correct the paths.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this kind of error. But I just change the `Network service` to `Local system in Log On As` tab.

Follow my step-by-step below to resolve it:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type: `services.msc`, then looking for `MongoDB Server (MongoDB)`
2. Double click on `MongoDB Server (MongoDB)`.
3. Then it will open properties tab. On that tab click on `Log On`
4. After that check two items i.e. `Local System account` and `Allow service to interact with desktop`
5. After that press Apply and OK button. That's it, cheers!!
6. Open command prompt and copy the following command:- 
   "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongo.exe"

**NOTE:** This Tricks is work on my Windows 8.1 PC.

Answer (score 1):

Comment out string with `mp:` in configuration file: `%ProgramFiles%\MongoDB\Server\x.x\bin\mongod.cfg`

Like this:

```
...
#snmp:
#mp:
```

Answer (score 0):

Click Windows+r, type lusemgr.msc , Go to Groups and double click Administrators, Click Add, Click Advanced and click Find Now. Double click in Network Service (in bottom list) and click OK.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Installing in the other locations other than the windows directory caused me this error. Reinstalling the setup with the recommended method of "complete" fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs if you have Windows version previous to Windows 10.
Install the following update before installing MongoDB. Click on the link below.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs if you have Windows version previous to Windows 7. Install the following update by going to below link you have to download 
[Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9CDU.png)

#You have to download and install then go to servies.msu and start MongoDB server by Start also go into log on and set to #local machine

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

You may also need Microsoft Visual C++ (2015 worked for my Windows 8.1)