# Installing MongoDB. failed to start service

Tags: mongodb

Cannot find much on the internet about this problem. I even reset my computer because other things were messing up and it was about time i reset everything anyway. How ever I am still getting this error when I try to install it. I saw another post about it but it seemed it only applied to Windows 7, and I use Windows 10. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT - I have solved my problem. I downloaded Java and it didn't install so i checked for updates and i Updated my system and it worked.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQfnB.png)

Comment: Just to be sure: you have started the installer with full administrative privileges?

Comment: Don't provide textual error messages as linked images. Put them in the text of the question as searchable, copyable text.

Comment: I mean I can't run as Administrator. but I've never encountered a problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into this

http://blog.iswix.com/2008/09/different-year-same-problem.html

To confirm, with the installer on the abort, retry, ignore, cancel dialog up... go into services.msc and set the username and password manually. If you get a message saying the user was granted logon as a service right, try hitting retry on the MSI dialog and see if it starts.

It could also be missing dependencies or exceptions being thrown in your code.

Also,

[Error 1920 service failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061057/error-1920-service-failed-to-start-verify-that-you-have-sufficient-privileges-t)

Comment: So I should go to my service > right click mongodb > click propers > and click log on > and then type the password and username?

Comment: simply type services on your windows machine. Find mongodb in the list, double click and you will find a log on there. Do it there! Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt in administrator mode(Windows) and navigate to the directory having the .msi file. 
Now directly install it, by just writing the filename in the command line, itll be installed.